# Call a void function from another file

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I'm creating an app that has a start button (class StartButton) and i want that button calls a method from another class (class NewRide), but how can i call a void function from another file?

```
class StartButton extends StatefulWidget{
 @override
  _StartButtonState createState() => _StartButtonState();
}
class _StartButtonState extends State<StartButton> {
  String _driverState = 'offline';

  @override
  Widget build(context){
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Start'),
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          if (_driverState == 'offline') {
            _driverState = 'online';
          } else {
            _driverState = 'offline';
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is New Ride class, it has the void function i want to call when i press start button.

```
class NewRide extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewRideState createState() => _NewRideState();
}

class _NewRideState extends State<NewRide> {
  int _counter = 60;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void startTimer() {
      _counter = 60;
      if (_timer != null) {
        _timer.cancel();
      }
      _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          if (_counter > 0) {
            _counter--;
          } else {
            _timer.cancel();
          }
        });
      });
    }

    _showNewRideAlert() {
      if (_counter == 0) {
        return Text('Counter == 0');
      } else {
        return Text('Counter != 0');
      }
    }

    return _showNewRideAlert();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this for experiment purpose? If not I would use something like provider if I had to share any state/functions between two widgets.

Comment: Yes, i want to learn how to access something inside a class, from another.

Comment: `startTimer` is declared as a local function within the `build` method. It's not possible to call it from another file or really from anywhere outside of that `build` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **GlobalKey** and make startTimer public and change NewRideState to _ NewRideState

```
class StartButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartButtonState createState() => _StartButtonState();
}

class _StartButtonState extends State<StartButton> {
  String _driverState = 'offline';
  GlobalKey<NewRideState> newRideKey = GlobalKey<NewRideState>();
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        NewRide(key: newRideKey),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Start'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (_driverState == 'offline') {
                _driverState = 'online';
              } else {
                _driverState = 'offline';
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}



class NewRide extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewRide({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  NewRideState createState() => NewRideState();
}

class NewRideState extends State<NewRide> {
  int _counter = 60;
  Timer _timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _showNewRideAlert() {
      if (_counter == 0) {
        return Text('Counter == 0');
      } else {
        return Text('Counter != 0');
      }
    }

    return _showNewRideAlert();
  }

  void startTimer() {
    _counter = 60;
    if (_timer != null) {
      _timer.cancel();
    }
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        if (_counter > 0) {
          _counter--;
        } else {
          _timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First import the other file/class into the main class (I'm not sure what your file is called).

`import '.../newRide.dart' as newRide;`

Then call the function like this:

```
newRide._showNewRideAlert();
```

It might not work due to how the class/state is setup though (the widget won't be built). So you may have to move the code into a place that is callable, such as the top of the class or implement the function into the page where it is used.

Comment: Thanks! But i want to call ```void startTimer()```, so i tried ```newRide.startTimer()```; but didnt work. It says The Function 'startTimer' isnt defined.

Comment: It would work if the function was directly in the class but it’s in the extended class which is why it wouldn’t work, you can make a custom class.